# C++ Stack implementation using std::list

Tags: c++, performance, linked-list, stack

I have the following 'interface' to the C++ `std::list` and I was wondering how I could make it go faster. In particular, it needs to be able to evaluate up to two million operations in a matter of a couple seconds. Right now it's at around 8 seconds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

int main()
{

    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;

    std::list<int> myList (n);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < m; i++) {
        std::string op;
        std::cin >> op;
        if (op[1] == 'O') {
            std::cout << myList.back() << '\n';
            myList.pop_back();
        } else {
            int val;
            std::cin >> val;
            myList.push_back(val);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It reads input in the form

```
3 4
PUSH 2
PUSH 3
POP
POP
```

With expected output

```
3
2
```

Where 3 corresponds to highest value, and 4 corresponds to number of operations.

The operations are guaranteed to be safe (no POPing empty stacks), and each value is used at most once (this part in particular I feel I could optimize, but I'm not sure how).

Right now I'm testing with the following Python script:

```
print "1000000 2000000"

for val in xrange(1,1000001):
    print "PUSH ", val

for _ in xrange(0,1000000):
    print "POP"
```

And getting this for time:

> ```
> 8.89 real         0.00 user         0.01 sys
> ```

I started out using `std::stack`, but tried switching to `std::list` in order to give a preset size, so as to not need to reallocate memory. This did not help the time any, but that's where it stands as of now.

Comment: Changing to `std::vector` increased `user` and `sys`, and `real` remained about the same. `8.76 real         7.29 user         1.44 sys`

Comment: The way you parse input can also be a big factor. Maybe you could get rid of the Python code, and post full code that you use for benchmarking? It should be easier to answer the question then.

Comment: The full test code is 2 million lines... it goes `PUSH 1\nPUSH 2\n...PUSH 1000000\nPOP\nPOP...POP`

Comment: That `0.00 user` in your question is not really believable, are you sure that your test or copy/paste was accurate (and repeatable)? Also make sure you're timing only the C++ part, not the python generator (store the output of the generator in a file, and time only the C++ part).

Comment: Can you put the test data file somewhere we can download?

Comment: the test data can be generated from that python script... do you want it in an additional location?

Comment: @LokiAstari - I ran the python script and sent the output to a file. The program reads from that file. This completely separates the python generation from the code execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> std::list<int> myList (n);
> ```

This does not do what you think it does. It creates a list of `n` elements. If you're using C++11, they're all garbage because those `n` elements are default-initialized. Fortunately, you'll never run across those garbage values. Your calls to `push_back` allocate a new chunk of memory.

You don't want to use a list. Use a vector.

When I run your program on my computer, compiled with optimization level 3, I get timing results of

```
6.64 real         6.32 user         0.32 sys
```

So comparable results. Let's trim your function down a bit in size. Let's trim it down a lot!

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> int main()
> {   
>     int n, m;
>     std::cin >> n >> m;
>     for (int i = 0 ; i < m; i++) {
>         std::string op; 
>         std::cin >> op; 
>         if (op[1] == 'O') {
>         } else {
>             int val;
>             std::cin >> val;
>         }   
>     }   
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

The only logic that's left is reading the input. When I run this on my computer, I get timing results of

```
 5.23 real         5.22 user         0.00 sys
```

Almost all of the wall clock time is reading the file. C++ I/O is notoriously slow. If you need to read, parse, and write millions of lines in a couple of seconds I suggest you revert back to C I/O. And don't use `fscanf`. It, too, is slow. Take advantage of the known format of the input file. Read a line. If the second character is `'O'` you have a `POP`. Otherwise you have a `PUSH val`. Parse the integer that starts at the character after the `H`, or the fifth character (character position 4).

**Update**

It turns out the compiler and standard c++ library makes a big difference. Reporting only the real times (first item from /usr/bin/time),

```
Version     g++-5/libstdc++   clang++-3.7/libc++
Original    4.79 seconds      7.29 seconds
Untie       0.65              5.90
Vector      0.50              5.71
Getline     0.25              3.11
C I/O       0.28              0.28
```

The `getline` version is even faster than is the C-based I/O version in the case of using g++. Clang, in this case, bites. Or perhaps it's the standard C library.

Here's the getline version:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main()
{   
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio (false);
    std::cin.tie (nullptr);

    int n, m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    std::cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');

    std::vector<int> stack;
    stack.reserve (n);

    char line[256];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < m; i++)
    {
        std::cin.getline (line, sizeof(line));
        if (line[1] == 'O')
        {
            std::cout << stack.back() << '\n';
            stack.pop_back (); 
        }
        else
        {
            stack.push_back (std::atoi(line+4));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After converting to vectors and C-style I/O, the exact same input file yields timing results of  `0.28 real         0.27 user         0.01 sys` on my computer. I'm going to leave those conversions as an exercise for the questioner.

Comment: They are not `default-initialized` they are `zero-initialized`. For `int` this means they are zero.

Comment: `C++ I/O is notoriously slow`: This is actually false and has been shown to be false on SO several times. Now; It is hard to compete with C I/O but it is close (The problem us usually caused by user failure. Especially excessive flushing and syncing the C++ IO streams with the C IOstream. Turn off the sync with `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` and don't use `std::endl` as much)  See: [Performance Difference Between C and C++ Style File IO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17468088/14065) especially the answer by [Konrad Rudolph](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17468320/14065)

Comment: Would you recommend reading using `gets`/`gets_s` then?

Comment: Whoa! I'd recommend you not use clang combined with libc++. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

C++ std::cin and std::cout are both tied together and and tied to C stdin and C stdout respectively. This causes a lot of performance problems when dealing with std::cin and std::cout.

You can help the situation by using:

```
std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);   // Disconnect from C IO
std::cin.tie(NULL);                      // Disconnect in from out (otherwise they flush).
```

If you change the code to use `std::fstream` (rather than std::cin/std::cout) you can get even better performance.

I did some experiments and reading a line and parsing the line separately improves things even more.

```
 std::getline(std::cin, line);
 if (line[1] == 'O') {
     // STUFF
 }
 else {
     int  val;
     std::stringstream  linestream(&line[5]);
     linestream >> val;
     // STUFF;
 }
```

Also you should be using vector rather than list. It has two advantages: 1) You can allocate all the space you need in advance. 2) Spacial locality can make access faster.

Times:

```
 As written:  real  0m5.119s   user  0m4.751s   sys  0m0.362s
 Use vector:  real  0m4.906s   user  0m4.585s   sys  0m0.325s
 Un Tie:      real  0m4.247s   user  0m4.233s   sys  0m0.017s
 std::getline real  0m1.559s   user  0m1.546s   sys  0m0.017s
 std::fstream real  0m0.804s   user  0m0.766s   sys  0m0.022s


 C Version    real  0m0.434s   user  0m0.422s   sys  0m0.016s
```